# dd /dev/sda to img on drive

Tags: linux, disk-space, dd, disk-image

If I run:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/image.img bs=1M
```

Will the `image.img` (which is located on `/dev/sda1`) be continuously copied onto itself? As it gets bigger from data, will that additional data be written in the image and continue forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will run out of disk space before the operation completes. The disk image `image.img` will be unusable.

Comment: Oh! Wow i completely overlooked that. But technically if lets say the image.img was stored near the beginning of the block of the hard drive, would the image copy itself, or is there a RAM buffer of sorts

Comment: Yes, you might get a partial copy of `image.img` in the image itself. No, it won't go on indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an object trying to eat itself. To contain itself in addition to itself it must be at least twice as big.

Comment: Nothing can be twice as big as itself. :)

Comment: Hence we have a contradiction!